# How can I know the object type sent by a socket?

Tags: java, object, stream

I am using **Java**. I make connection using sockets and I send from the server objects using `ObjectOutputStream`. There is two types of object that can be sent, one type is object which is instance of **class A** and the other type which is instance of **class B**.
When I read Object in the client side, how can I decide if it is instance of **class A** or instance of **class B**?

PS: I have accsess to these classes in the client side too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simples solution is to use `instanceof` operator on input:

```
final Object obj = inputStream.readObject();
if(obj instanceof A) {
  final A a = (A)obj;
} else {
  final B a = (B)obj;
}
```

Slightly redundant solution (but avoiding `instanceof`) would be to send some type byte first (`0` - `A`, `1` - `B`).

Comment: but it comes as Object type isnt it?

Comment: Yes, that's why you need downcasting.

Comment: What's the purpose of all the finals?

Comment: @SteveKuo: after working with functional languages your mind shifts to immutable types everywhere. No real purpose, but I use them whenever I can

Answer (score 2):

Either use

```
if (object instanceof ClassA) {
```

or

```
if (object.getClass() == ClassA.class) {
```

The difference is that the first will also be true when object is of a sub-class of ClassA or implements ClassA (when it's an interface), while the second one will only be true when it's exactly that class.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the instanceof operator is the best method.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, use a plaintext form of serialisation & embed the name of the type (or perhaps deserialisation strategy) in the serialised payload. This way you can inspect the payload before deserialising.

Comment: And how will that help? It's the same question, what object was sent?

Comment: Right, yes. Note to self: don't answer SO questions 2 minutes after waking up. Changed my answer.